# es6 calling a function in map loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following code works fine.

```
function getProducts(params) {
    return params.productQuantities
        .map(prod => ({
            purchaseOrderLine: null,
            haulerCostCode: getOrderLine(params, prod).haulCostCode,
            productCostCode: getOrderLine(params, prod).productCostCode,
            typeOfWork: getOrderLine(params, prod).productCostCode,
        }))
        .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
            accumulator.push(currentValue);
            return accumulator;
        }, []);
}

function getOrderLine(params, ticketLine) {
    return params.orderDetail.order.orderLineItems
        .find(orderLine => orderLine.id == ticketLine.id);
}
```

My question is how do I avoid multiple calls to getOrderLine()?

Comment: `prod => { let line = getOrderLine(); return { ... }; }`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with es6 or map(). Making the function call first, storing the result, then using it multiple times is simple refactoring.

Comment: Yeah your `=>` function automatically is  returning  the contents of `()`, but you don't have to do it that way. If you use the `() => { /*some code */ return something; }`  you can run arbitrary code and then return something after that code.

Comment: Yay! The functional paradigm propagation let's people forget about variables ...

Comment: Does `getOrderLine` return more than those three properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a function body instead of a function expression:

```
.map(prod => {
   const o = getOrderLine(params, prod);
   return {
     purchaseOrderLine: null,
     haulerCostCode: o.haulCostCode,
     productCostCode: o.productCostCode,
     typeOfWork: o.productCostCode,
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use function composition -

```
const comp = (f, g) =>
  x => f(g(x))

const getOrderLine = params => ticketLine =>
  params.orderDetail.order.orderLineItems
    .find(orderLine => orderLine.id == ticketLine.id)

const makeProduct = orderLine =>
  ( { purchaseOrderLine: null
    , haulerCostCode: orderLine.haulCostCode
    , productCostCode: orderLine.productCostCode
    , typeOfWork: orderLine.productCostCode
    }
  )

const getProducts = params =>
    params.productQuantities
      .map(comp(makeProduct, getOrderLine(params)))
```

I removed the `reduce` bit because it's doesn't make any sense. `map` already creates a new array.

There's other serious problems here though. These functions are digging into object properties sometimes three levels deep. This creates a tight coupling in you code base. See [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)